# Can a connected planar compactum minus a point be totally disconnected?

Tags: gn.general-topology

What the title said.  In a slightly more leisurely fashion:-

> Let $X$ be a compact, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with more than one point, and let $x\in X$.  Can $X\smallsetminus\{x\}$ be totally disconnected?

Note that the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) shows that, in the absence of the compactness hypothesis, the answer can be 'yes'.

To give credit where it's due, this question was inspired by one that I was asked by Barry Simon.

Comment: I'm almost embarrassed to say this, but perhaps you want to add the condition that X has more than one point.  

Comment: Do you have an example of non-planar one?

Comment: Is there an example of a compact connected set such that no two points can be joined by a path?

Comment: I really like this question! If X were locally connected, I think we could apply Hahn-Mazurkiewicz ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn-Mazurkiewicz_theorem ), and then show [0,1] minus a closed set is never totally disconnected. But I don't know if that's relevant or not.

Comment: @gowers. Seach for pseudo-arc.

Comment: Anton, how about the one-point compactification of the rationals?

Comment: that can be inbedden in the plane, and it doesn't seem connected to me.

Comment: @Henry. What about continuum (=compact connected metric space)?

Comment: I agree with jef:  Don't $\mathbb Q \cap (-\sqrt2, \sqrt2)$ and its complement in the $1$-point compactification of $\mathbb Q$ separate that compactification?

Comment: jef, yes, you're right - it's not connected.  My mistake.  How do you embed it in the plane?

Comment: Now I'm confused about what you mean by the 1-point compactification of Q. The complement of a neighborhood of infinity in the usual 1-point compactification must be compact, so I don't see a disconnection. It's not the induced topology on the rationals plus infinity from the 1-point compactification of the reals. However, it's also not Hasudorff, and therefore can't be embedded in the plane.

Comment: Wait, now I agree with Douglas. Oh, I give up.

Comment: Whoops—per Douglas's answer, I forgot that closed, bounded subsets of $\mathbb Q$ need not remain closed in its $1$-point compactification.

Comment: douglas is right and I was wrong, I thought the compactification would be homeomorphic to the rational points on the unit circle, this is clearly wrong because it is not even hausdorff. I am still confused about the connectedness.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Being planar has nothing to do with the problem. Suppose a totally disconnects $X$ and choose $b$ different from $a$.  By passing to a sub continuum, assume that no proper sub continuum contains both $a$ and $b$. Take non empty disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ whose union is $ X\sim a$.  WLOG $b$ is in $U$, and observe that $U\cup \{a\}$ is closed and connected.

Comment: Bill, I'm sorry to look foolish:  What is a continuum here?  Is it a set of a certain cardinality, an image of an interval, a connected planar compactum, or something else?  (I am no topologist, so I assume that the term is standard; I just haven't encountered it.)  The “pass to a minimal sub-continuum” step worries me a little.

Comment: Oops, never mind, I see from above that it is a compact, connected metric space.

Comment: The intersection of a nested family of continua is again a continuum.   You are right to ask about this--it is the only place that compactness is needed.

Comment: I like this.  So, Bill, just to be clear, you're invoking Zorn's Lemma to construct your minimal continuum?

Comment: Yes, although by separability you can lower the logical strength a bit if you care about that.

Comment: Your argument is more natural (I simply do not feel comfortable with connected spaces --- path-connected are better).

Comment: Mine is maybe more elementary, Anton, but I like yours because it gives more information.  Being an analyst, I also prefer path connectness, and I had not realized before reading your argument that you can easily use path connectedness to study spaces that are not path connected.  I can see putting this to use on some problems on Lipschitz quotients.

Answer (score 22):

Let denote by $U_n\subset \mathbb R^2$ a sequence of open bounded neigborhoods of $X$, so that 
$$U_{n+1}\subset U_n\ \ \text{and}\ \  \bigcap_n U_n=X.$$
We can assume that all $U_n$ are connceted and therefore path-connected. Coose a point $p\in X$ distict from $x$ and consider a sequence of paths $\gamma_n$ in $U_n$ from $p$ to $x$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon<|p-x|$.
For each path choose the smalest value $t_n\in[0,1]$ so that $|\gamma_n(t_n)-x|=\epsilon$.
The image $Z_n=\gamma([0,t_n])$ is connected compact set.
Let $Z$ be a Hausdorff limit of a subsequence of $Z_n$.
Note that $Z$ is a compact connected subset of $X$.
Clearly, $Z\not\ni x$ and it contains at least two points; a contradiction

Comment: P.S. From Kuratowski embedding, any compact metric space is isometric to a subset of $L^\infty$. Thus the same argument works for any continuum (=compact connected metric space).

Comment: Oh, I see we "crossed paths", Anton.  Your proof also works for a general continuum by making the Hilbert cube the ambient space. It also shows that any minimal sub continuum joining two points can be written as a Hausdorff limit of (even piecewise linear) arcs in some suitable larger space.  

Comment: OK; another crossing of paths...

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, Anton.  I marked Bill's answer as accepted, for its extra simplicity.  If I had two ticks to give, I'd give them! 

Answer (score 10):

Two great answers have already been given, and I don't claim to add much, but here is something anyway.

A totally disconnected locally compact Hausdorff space has a basis of clopen sets, according to [Proposition 3.1.7 of Arhangel'skii and Tkachenko](http://books.google.com/books?id=B785AETmFKEC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q=&f=true), for example.  A closed set in $X-\{a\}$ need not be closed in $X$, but if $X$ is a metric space then the clopen subsets of $X-\{a\}$ at positive distance to $a$ will be clopen in $X$.  Thus if $X$ is a compact metric space with more than one point and $X-\{a\}$ is totally disconnected, then $X$ is not connected.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a related fact, and surprisingly couldn't find anything relevant, except of this question. Even though it was answered 10 years ago, perhaps the following result could be useful to somebody.

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a connected metric space that contains more than one point. Let $A\subset X$ be totally disconnected and locally compact with respect to the subspace topology. Then $A$ is nowhere dense.

**Proof.** First, let us show $int A =\varnothing$. Assume that $U$ is an open set in $X$ such that $\overline{U}$ is compact and contained in $A$, and $x\in U$. Since a totally disconnected locally compact paracompact space is zero-dimensional (see 6.2.9 in Engelking's General Topology), there is an open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $x$ that is clopen in $A$. Then, there are closed set $F$ in $X$ and open set $W$ in $X$ such that $V=A\cap F=A\cap W$. Since $V\subset U\subset A$, $V=U\cap W$ is open in $X$. Since $V\subset \overline{U}\subset A$, $V=\overline{U}\cap F$ is closed in $X$. Hence, $V$ is nonempty and clopen in $X$ which contradicts its connectedness.

Now recall that a locally compact set is open in its closure (see 3.3.9 in Engelking). Hence, $A=\overline{A}\cap U$, for some open $U\subset X$. Assume $int \overline{A}\ne\varnothing$. Then, there is $x\in int \overline{A} \cap A= int \overline{A} \cap\overline{A}\cap U=int \overline{A} \cap U\subset \overline{A} \cap U=A$, from where $x\in int \overline{A} \cap U\subset A$, and so $x\in int A$. Contradiction with the previous step.

**Corollary.** If $X$ is a connected complete metric space that contains more than one point, it cannot be covered by a countable collection of totally disconnected locally compact subsets.

**In particular**, we cannot remove a closed totally disconnected set (e.g. a single point) from a continuum to make it totally disconnected.