# Beyond Cantor's Teepee

Tags: gn.general-topology, path-connected, compactness

From *Counterexamples in Topology* by Steen and Seebach (2nd edition) example 129 page 145 we have an example of **connected and totally path-disconnected space**.
It is defined as follow:

Fix $p= (1/2,1/2)$. Let $C$ be the Cantor set in the unit interval $[0,1]$. Let $E \subset C$ be the subset of $C$ that is the endpoints of the removed intervals. Let $F = C \setminus E$.
Let $L( c)$ be the line segment connecting the point $c \in C $ to $p$.
Define $Y_E=\{(x, y)\in L( c)~|~ c \in E, y \in \mathbb Q \}$ and $Y_F=\{(x, y)\in L( c)~|~ c \in F, y \not\in \mathbb Q \}$
We define **Cantor's Leaky Tent** or **Cantor's Teepee** as $Y =Y_E \cup Y_F\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with the subspace topology.

I have two questions:

1. Is there another "well-know" example of connected and totally path-disconnected space?
2. Cantor's Teepee is not compact. Can we construct a non trivial compact, connected and totally path-disconnected space?

Comment: ["Spacebook"](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146) has a sort of "electronic index" of Steen and Seebach; searching for "Is Compact" + "Is Connected" + "Is Totally Path-Disconnected" turns up A Pseudo-Arc,
Finite Complement Topology on a Countable Space, and
One Point Compactification fo the Rationals.

Comment: Cantor's *toupee*? -click- Oh... well, that's disappointing :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I happened to run across an answer to 2. (and therefore 1.) just by clicking on one of the related MO links, finding the same question in a comment by Timothy Gowers under [MO16578](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16578/can-a-connected-planar-compactum-minus-a-point-be-totally-disconnected) that was later answered in a comment by Anton Petrunin, and then googling for more information. The key term you want seems to be "[pseudo-arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc)", apparently a construction very familiar to the point-set topology community.

A pseudo-arc is a continuum $X$ (a connected compact metrizable space) with more than one point such that no subcontinuum $A$ (a subspace that is a continuum) is a union of two proper subcontinua of $A$. Remarkably, all pseudo-arcs are homeomorphic to one another!

Answer (score 3):

The order topology provides many examples of compact connected ordered sets which are totally path disconnected. A totally ordered set is said to be complete if it complete as a lattice. A totally ordered set $X$ is said to be dense if whenever $x<y$ then there is some $z$ with $x<z<y$. One can get a totally ordered set that is both complete and dense by taking the Dedekind-MacNielle completion of a dense totally ordered set. A totally ordered set is compact in the order topology if and only if it is complete, and a totally ordered set is connected in the order topology if and only if it is dense and every bounded nonempty subset has a least upper bound. Therefore the dense complete total orders are precisely the compact connected total orders. On the other hand, except for the trivial cases, a compact totally ordered set need not have any paths. To be more precise, if $X$ is a compact connected totally ordered set, then there is a path from a point $x$ to a point $y$ with $y>x$ if and only if the interval $[x,y]$ is order isomorphic to the unit interval in the real numbers.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to bring in density where you say "a totally ordered set is connected in the order topology if and only if every bounded nonempty subset has a least upper bound" (e.g., a finite totally ordered set has this l.u.b. property). For those interested, there's a nice paper by Pete Clark on this theme: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0973v1.pdf.

Comment: A complete dense Aronszajn line gives a concrete example which is very similar to $\mathbb{R}$ in almost every other way.